# Getting error when use LinkedList without Java buildin method

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to use LinkedList without using Java until but I am getting error message in the `head` function.

`head cannot be resolved to a variable Java(33554515)`

I thinks I have problem about  java access specifier. But I am not sure.
Here is my code

```
     class LL {
        class Node{
            String data;
            Node next;
    
            Node(String data){
                this.data=data;
                this.next=null;
            }
        }
        public void addFirst(String data){
            Node newNode = new Node(data);
            if(head==null){
                head=newNode;
                return;
            }
            newNode.next=head;
            head=newNode;
    
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LL list = new LL();
            list.addFirst("A");
            list.addFirst("B");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: First of all, I really think that you should use an IDE, such as Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA. They underline the problems in the code and handle compiling/building for you. And of course, through them, you would understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses a variable named `head`, but you never defined that variable.

At least you need to change your code as follows:

```
class LL {
    // Define a variable named head at LL level
    private Node head;

    ...
}
```

I also suggest to improve your code as follows:

- Define the visibility of each field and method (`public`, `private`, `protected`)
- Use a consistent formatting for the whole code. For example, if you decide to put a space between the name of class and the symbol {, do that for the whole code, for example change `class Node{` to `class Node {`
- Use comments when needed explaining something that is not evident by code, for example the comment `// add first` doesn't add anything to a method named `addFirst`